# Aggregation in MySQL sub query, seems slower than it should be

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, aggregation

I've been working on refactoring a bunch of application logic and SQL that has been plaguing our system for a while.

I had managed to get rid of the bulk of the application layer logic and get it all done in an SQL query, but it seems to be lagging a bit and I'm not sure why.

```sql
SELECT
  st.id                    ownerId,
  st.display_name          ownerLabel,
  COALESCE((score.mean_score / score.num_responses) * 100, 0)         meanScore,
  COALESCE((score.top_box_percentage / score.num_responses) * 100, 0) topBoxPercentage,
  COALESCE(score.num_responses, 0)      sampleSize
FROM question q
  CROSS JOIN store st
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
     COUNT(ch.id)                  num_responses,
     SUM(ans.mean_score_weight)    mean_score,
     SUM(ans.is_top_box)           top_box_percentage,
     q.id                          question_id,
     q.category_id                 category_id,
     st.id                         store_id
   FROM choice ch
     INNER JOIN response r ON r.id = ch.response_id
     INNER JOIN answer ans ON ans.id = ch.answer_id
     INNER JOIN store st ON st.id = r.store_id
     INNER JOIN question q ON q.id = ans.question_id
   WHERE r.survey_id = 96  AND r.created_at BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-03-01' AND q.is_scorable AND ans.is_scorable
   GROUP BY q.id, st.id
    ) score ON score.question_id = q.id AND score.store_id = st.id
WHERE q.survey_id = 96 AND q.is_scorable 
GROUP BY q.id, st.id;
```

The expected execution plan for this query is the following:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys                                  | key                    | key_len | ref                   | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | q          | ref    | question_FI_6                                  | question_FI_6          | 4       | const                 |   77 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | st         | ALL    | NULL                                           | NULL                   | NULL    | NULL                  |  339 |   100.00 | Using join buffer                            |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL                                           | NULL                   | NULL    | NULL                  | 3505 |   100.00 |                                              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | r          | ref    | PRIMARY,response_FI_3,response_FI_4            | response_FI_3          | 5       |                       | 5179 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | st         | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                        | PRIMARY                | 4       | titan.r.store_id      |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ch         | ref    | unique_response_answer,choice_FI_1,choice_FI_3 | unique_response_answer | 4       | titan.r.id            |   35 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ans        | eq_ref | PRIMARY,answer_FI_1                            | PRIMARY                | 4       | titan.ch.answer_id    |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED     | q          | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                        | PRIMARY                | 4       | titan.ans.question_id |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

It seems to me like the reason for the slow query is the filesort + temporary sorting table on `response`. My experience with MySQL is rather limited so I'm not sure how to get around this. Any help would be appreciated.

`response` indexes:

```
+----------+------------+--------------------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name                       | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------+------------+--------------------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| response |          0 | PRIMARY                        |            1 | id             | A         |       53911 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| response |          1 | response_FI_3                  |            1 | survey_id      | A         |         104 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| response |          1 | response_FI_4                  |            1 | store_id       | A         |         523 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| response |          1 | fk_response_competition_id_idx |            1 | competition_id | A         |          13 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------+------------+--------------------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

While writing this post is occurred to me that I could be making use of ordering by the key used (response_FI_3 = r.survey_id) to get rid of the filesort, which produced mildly better results, but I'm still under the belief that more can be done to improve this query.

Grateful for any input provided.

Comment: If you see `Using filesort` that means that your query is using columns in the where clause that don't have an index on them. From what i see, `created_at` column might be the culprit. You're using that column in the `WHERE` but you don't have an index on it. And you have a similar issue with the `question` table but without the list of indexes on that table i can't tell you where it is.

Comment: Ah thanks, that makes it a lot clearer! I managed to get rid of "Using filesort" on the response table by sorting on an indexed column (r.survey_id). I imagine I can do the same with question then given this. Is there any significant cause behind why MySQL is using a temporary table for both of those data sets?

Comment: Temporary tables are created for several reasons. It's quite normal when you are using aggregation functions like `GROUP BY`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html

Comment: Thanks for the point in the right direction, seems like:

"If there is an ORDER BY clause and a different GROUP BY clause, or if the ORDER BY or GROUP BY contains columns from tables other than the first table in the join queue, a temporary table is created."

Is the cause. I'll have a go at fixing these issues when I get the chance and hopefully update my question with how I solved it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LEFT` may be causing the problem.  Can you get rid of it?  Notice that the Optimizer (as viewed in the EXPLAIN) failed to start with the subquery.

`survey_id = 96  AND r.created_at` says that `r` needs the 'compound index' `INDEX(survey_id, created_at)`.  Please do SHOW CREATE TABLE.

You don't really have a `CROSS JOIN`, so let me propose this rewrite:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT ... ) AS score
    JOIN store AS st  ON score.store_id = st.id
    JOIN question q   ON score.question_id = q.id
    WHERE q.survey_id = 96 AND q.is_scorable
    GROUP BY q.id, st.id;
```

`BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-03-01'` -- If the column is "DATE", then this range falsely(?) included March 1.  If it id "DATETYPE", it includes and extra midnight.

Have you experimented with the subquery on its own?  Is it ok, or should we look into it?  Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE for each tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you see `Using filesort` that means that your query is using columns in the where clause that don't have an index on them. From what i see, `created_at` column might be the culprit. You're using that column in the `WHERE` but you don't have an index on it. And you have a similar issue with the `question` table but without the list of indexes on that table i can't tell you where it is.